# To find the Jordan Canonical Form

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

Consider a matrix A (5x5) with all entries = 1. Here the entries are considered as elements of $F_5$ ,the finite field of order 5.

What is the Jordan canonical form?

I have found out that $A^2=0$ and thus the minimal polynomial is $x^2$.
So I know there are (two 2x2 blocks and one 1x1 block) OR (one 2x2 block and three 1x1 blocks)

How do I tell which?

Comment: You haven't stated the size of the matrix explicitly, but from your work it sounds like $A$ is $5 \times 5$. Please add this to your question.

Comment: added. thank you

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** If $A$ is an $n \times n$ matrix, then $n - \operatorname{rk}(A)$ is the total number of Jordan blocks that $A$ has associated with $\lambda = 0$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint.* Consider the rank of $A$.

Comment: rank =4 and is same for JCF. So it contains two 2x2 blocks and one 1x1 block. Am I right? and thank you 
Edit - bad mistake. rank = 1

Comment: also curious,if for some higher order matrix both wold have same ranks then how do I tell which is the JCF?

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person The rank isn't 4. How did you get that?

Comment: sorry. major error. It's 1. hence the latter option.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Yes, it's rank-1. In general, if $A$ is nilpotent, you need to consider the ranks of $A,A^2,A^3$ and so on. The sequence of ranks will determine the Jordan form uniquely.

Comment: @Angry_Math_Person Even more generally, the set of *nullities* of $(A-\lambda_iI),(A-\lambda_iI)^2,(A-\lambda_iI)^3,\ldots$ for all eigenvalues $\lambda_i$ of $A$ will uniquely determine the Jordan form of a general matrix $A$. In older books, these nullities are known as Weyr's characteristics of the matrix $A$. (Modern textbooks seem to leave them unnamed.)

Comment: @user1551 at least in Horn and Johnson, they've kept the name

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Thanks for the info. My copy is the first edition, which doesn't cover Weyr characteristic or Weyr form.